# Bootstrap: toggle navbar-fixed-bottom to navbar-fixed-top after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using bootstrap's navbar with built-in scrollspy function in an one page layout. (like in this example: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/)

I want to place the navbar at the bottom in the `#intro` section and to become fixed at the top when scrolling down.

**Question:**

How to prevent the navbar from jumping up and down (both when scrolling and when clicking a navigation element)?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Solution:**

I solved the problem by adding some CSS to the demo mentioned above:

```
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

and changed the jQuery code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
   var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 50;
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
             $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
         }
         else {
             $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
         }
    });
});
```

For demo look JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/90jbhe54/

Now it works nice and fluently.

Comment: So the problem is that up and down when you click on About ??

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to prevent this behavior?